# How to redirect multiple URL's to the same URL.

Tags: seo, redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect, yoast

I have been searching for a solution to this but can't find a good answer. I am trying to achieve the following through Wordpress with the Yoast SEO plugin.

Here is what I am trying to do:
I need to redirect certain directories and their pages to a subdomain.

Example: 
www.example.com/directory1/lots-of-pages-here
to 
subdomain.example.com/directory1/lots-of-pages-here

Here is the potential curveball. I don't want to migrate everything from www. to subdomain. I still want to keep specific pages on www.example.com so I can't wildcard everything.

I got to believe there is an easy approach here but I'm just not finding it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are there pages within that subdirectory that need to stay?  If so you will need a list of the pages to redirect, can you produce that?

Comment: www.example.com is a WP setup. How about subdomain.example.com/directory1/. Its a separate WP or its same WP? If it is separate then it shouldn't be hard I guess.

Comment: Is `/directory1` a physical directory or a URL-path within WordPress?

Comment: There are too many questions to answer this properly.   Please address these points by editing your question.